# My form is not taking the default value

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

This may be a silly thing to ask but I have the following:

```
<input ng-model="product.quantity" min="1" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" />
```

But I can't get the form starts blank.

How can I ensure that the form will be filled with, at least a value of "1"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form value is being set by the `ngModel` value and will ignore the `value` attribute. Set your model!

```
$scope.product.quantity = 1;
```